# preferred_choices entity field form never run

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to set a form with a "preferred_choices" on top of my select field HTML corresponding to previous submitted datas selected by the user. I want to construct an entity field with a constant list AND a preferred_choices top element if the form is previously submitted.

I never ran correctly this function in symfony2. 
Can you help me to construct correctly my field form.

Why my preferred_choices options select nothing when the form is construct ?
I setting this with correct object setted previously in the code.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $defaultCQSsearch = new CqsProSansMarque();
    $defaultCQSsearch->setRayLibelle((!array_key_exists('ray_libelle', $options['attr'])) ? null : $options['attr']['ray_libelle']);
    $defaultCQSsearch->setFamLibelle((!array_key_exists('fam_libelle', $options['attr'])) ? null : $options['attr']['fam_libelle']);
    $defaultCQSsearch->setCaeLibelle((!array_key_exists('cae_libelle', $options['attr'])) ? null : $options['attr']['cae_libelle']);

    $builder
        ->add('ray_libelle', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ApplicationDriveBundle:CqsProSansMarque',
            'data_class' => 'Application\DriveBundle\Entity\CqsProSansMarque',
            'property' => 'ray_libelle',
            'query_builder' => function(CqsProSansMarqueRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->select('a')
                ->groupBy('a.ray_libelle');
            },
            'preferred_choices' => array($defaultCQSsearch),
            'label' => 'rayon',
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`preferred_choices` option expects an array of values but you are passing an array of object (i.e. `$defaultCQSsearch`)

Comment: The symfony's doc is to short. Can you tell me what represent the values or key-value exactly for this options ?

Comment: see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#preferred-choices

Comment: Symfony's doc is too short and don't explain correctly the preferred_choices options. You think this option attempt array of values and doc give example of string value and when I use string value I have a warning error. I post a question because is not enough to read this little part of doc for run correctly. I need to understand exaclty.